# Testing GLM with anova output interpretation

Tags: r, output, glm, anova, interpretation

I have done some analyses in R using GLMs. 
After fitting the right model to the data, I usually test my model with

```
anova(model, test="F")
```

or

```
anova(model, test="chi")
```

depending on the distribution.

For the F-test I get an output with the following 6 columns:

```
 Df | Deviance | Resid. Df | Resid. Dev |     F  |  Pr(>F)
```

Is it ok to quote the result of the test like:

```
F(df, Resid.Df)=F, p= Pr(>F)
```

If I perform the Chi-sq test on the model, 
I get an output with the following 5 columns:

```
 Df | Deviance | Resid. Df | Resid. Dev |  Pr(>Chi)
```

What do I have to report here?
I read that Deviance is corresponding to the Chi-squared value.
So is it ok to report something like:

```
X^2=Deviance, df=df, p=Pr(>Chi)
```

and is df in this case df or residual df?

And a general question: is it appropriate to report GLM statistics like that?

I would appreciate any help or literature recommendation very much!
Thanks!

Comment: Conventions for reporting results of statistical tests vary by citation style, and thus by field and journal. I found [this page](http://web.psych.washington.edu/writingcenter/writingguides/pdf/stats.pdf) for APA with a quick google search- I suggest you look around for something similar for whatever citation style you plan to use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I did a google search and found advices to cite output of different statistical tests. However, I did not find a good practice to cite GLM. And perhaps my major problem is to understand the theory behind the difference of df and resid. df in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with the report like:

```
X^2=Deviance, df=df, p=Pr(>Chi)
```

and df=**df**, not **residual df**.